# AngularJS/Ionic how to initialize a controller's code without rendering the view?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an app where I have a number of controllers. I'm watching for a web socket message in my chatController which is connected to a inbox.html view. The app starts on the 'requests' page where the controller is different. The problem is unless the user has explicitly visited the inbox.html view at least once, the web socket(Socket.io) event isn't detected since the code for the 'chatController' hasn't been initialised. What options do I have for enabling this functionality? I would like to somehow initialise the code for the 'chatController' as soon as my app starts without the user having to visit the screen.

Thank you

Comment: Put the web socket event stuff into a service?

Comment: The service won't be injected into that controller unless it's initialized once.

Comment: Right. So you inject the service into whatever controller is handling the 'requests' page.